# How to edit a css file in ASP.NET using C# to change the website design

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I need to make a feature in the website where the admin can change designs of elements like Textbox, header, body and footer and fonts.

I tried
`string[] lines= File.ReadAllLines();` method to read all lines and
`File.WriteAllLines()` to write all the lines after modifying a particular line.

I have adjusted the css to fit each style of the elements in single line for each.

After `File.WriteAllLines` method, lines  sometimes written in a new line, which will affect all other element styles as it depends on line number.

Comment: Please give a concise, concrete example of what you are doing and what you are expecting.

Comment: On the website, Admin will select his desired colors, fonts, header color, background image etc and saves them by clicking on a button, this should save in the css file. No manual css editing, it should be dynamic.
I'll try any other methods too.

Comment: I think you need to be much more specific in this bit: "lines sometimes written in a new line"

Comment: I will have to replace existing line by new line which I'll build in code by getting colors from page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what WriteAllLines() does:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false, encoding))
{
    foreach (string str in contents)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

If any of the strings in 'contents' contains new line  ('\n' or '\r\n') then you'll get extra lines written to the file.

Perhaps instead of using WriteAllLines, you could write your own method, that replaces any '\n' or \r\n' in the output before writing them.

e.g.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false, encoding))
{
    foreach (string str in contents)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(str.Replace("\r","").Replace("\n",""));
    }
}
```

Comment: str.Replace("\n","");
This helped to avoid new lines in a line, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In C#:
Somewhat like this

```
TextboxName.Style.Add("font-size", "14px");
```

Comment: It is same but I'll write font-size:14px in css file.
This will apply to entire page or I can use css to other pages as well.